# Nothing happens when I trigger event with Backbone

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, tdd, jasmine

I try to get started with Backbone. I have the following JS:

```
var Question = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
          title: "Enter your question",
          type: "smallTextField",
          editMode: true
        };
      },

    initialize: function() {
          if (!this.get("title")) {
            this.set({"title": this.defaults.title});
          }
        },   

    toggleEditMode: function() {
        !this.get("editMode");
    },

    clear: function() {
        this.destroy();
      }         

});
```

Collection:

```
var Questions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.bind("add", options.view.addQuestionView);
    }
});
```

AppView:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),

    initialize: function () {
        this.questions = new Questions( null, { view: this });
    },

    events: {
        "click #addQuestion":  "addQuestionModel"
    },

    addQuestionModel: function() {
            var model = new Question();
            this.questions.add(model);
    },

    addQuestionView: function(model) {
        $("#questionBox").append("<div>" + model.get('title') + "</div>");  
    },

}); 

    var appview = new AppView;
```

and the following HTML:

```
<div id="questionBox"></div>
<a href="#" id="addQuestion">Add question</a>
```

In my Jasmine spec, I trigger $("#addQuestion").click();

However - nothing happens when I run the test. E.g. it seems like no function is bound to the #addQuestion's click event.

I guess something is done wrong, and I can simply not figure out what it is.

Any idea?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/6dT6N/ I hope you have a proper HTML in your jasmine, I mean that your `a#addQuestion` is properly placed into a `body` tag, so the `events` selector can match it.

Comment: I'm tented to edit your question to remove all the code is adding no more than noise, do we need the Model and Collection implementation here?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a # in your id? Is it a typo?
Try removing it (id="addQuestion")

Also, are you sure you have initialized the view before triggering your click?
Usually, when events are not triggered it's because they're set on an element that's out of the view's scope (for instance on a link not included in your view "el"). But since you're using body, I don't see how it can come from there (unless you modified it in your post).
So my guess would be that your jQuery selector is not really useful here.
Try:

```
el: "body"
```

instead of:

```
el: $("body")
```

Comment: Just a typo introduced after I modified the code a bit before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I have this issue, it's related to the fact that the properties on the object literal you're passing into the Backbone view are being evaluated before jQuery and the DOM have fully loaded.

Here's an [excellent post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/) that describes the problem and several solutions.